# A puzzle on the branching factor of MySQL B+ tree

Tags: mysql, data-structures, tree, innodb, b-tree

In [B+ Tree wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree), we could see that

> The order, or branching factor, **b** of a B+ tree measures the capacity of nodes (i.e., the number of children nodes, typically 100+) for internal nodes in the tree. The actual number of children for a node, referred to here as **m**, is constrained for internal nodes so that  `b / 2 < m < b`.

AFAIK, the size of a tree node is typically fixed, [like in MySQL, the default page size is 16K](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-init-startup-configuration.html). I wonder how to make sure that **m** is bigger than **b / 2** if the search keys in the internal node are too large? for example a big search key is **1K**, so an internal node can only contain at most 16 search keys, which is far less than 100, right?

Another question how to determine the branching factor **b**?

Comment: A 1K search key is not typical.  You have to optimize for the most common cases.  The extreme cases will always have performance problems.

Comment: Yes, 1K is not a common case. I just want to know how B+ tree determine its branching factor and make sure `b / 2 < m < b` in this corner case. @TimRoberts

Comment: I don't think MySQL has a document that shows how they do splitting, although since it's open source, you could go look it up.